# Which is the Best power management to maximize runtime on battery?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, voltage-regulator, power-electronics, boost

I have 3 circuits

Circuit 1 8V 400mA

Circuit 2 5V 700mA

Circuit 3  3.3V 40mA

Battery 4.2V lipo 3000mAh

Option 1 – 4.2v to 8V booster 1.2A and 5v regulator, 3.3v regulator

Option 2 – 4.2v to 5V booster 750mA,3.3 regulator and 4.2v to 8v booster 400mA

Circuit 3 is always operating

Circuit 1 and 2 do not operate continuously

Comment: Best would be when boosters are off when circuits not needed as they draw power doing nothing.

Comment: And you have been told: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/520803/152903

Comment: You should calculate the power drawn from every circuit (do this by multiplying volts to drawn current on every stage + Iq of regulators), Sum compare and you will get which is best.

Comment: @Solar Mike please check last comment on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/520803/152903

Comment: So where are the datasheets for these items so you can check for yourself - as shown by the answer given to the other post.

Comment: If you've chosen the boosters already, why don't you calculate it?